# Will port down event cause TCP or other connection broken in linux TCPIP stack?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, ip

I'm working on cloud, customer need our virtual switch to keep its VM's TCP based connection while our virtual switch upgrading (which is stop virtual switch first and then start new virtual switch). We use ovs, in this case, port of VM will link down and link up in 1 second. Customer's OS is linux.

So I'm thinking if this link down/up will cause the TCP connection broken in VM? I have no idea which part of code in TCPIP stack I should read, as boss tells me I have to show him code other than some blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP/IP is expressly designed to survive such outages. If your boss insists on seeing code, you will have to show him the entire Linux IP stack, and much good may it do him. More probably you should just refer him to [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) and [793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793).